# Disable Joomla debug mode in command line script

Tags: debugging, configuration, joomla, overriding, command-line-interface

I have a joomla cli data script that fails (out of memory) when "debug system" is enabled in global configuration because there is a memory leak in JDatabaseDriver::execute().
I would like to disable "debug system" at the beginning of this script.
It would help me if I could override the configuration.php file content programmatically.

My script looks like this :

```
const _JEXEC = 1;

// Load system defines
if (file_exists(dirname(__DIR__) . '/defines.php'))
{
    require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__DIR__));
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/import.legacy.php';
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/cms.php';
require_once JPATH_CONFIGURATION . '/configuration.php';

class Importdata extends JApplicationCli
{
    //...
}

JApplicationCli::getInstance('Importdata')->execute();
```

The memory exhausted error happens in /joomla/database/driver/mysqli.php on line 887 (mysqli_fetch_object) only when Joomla is in debug mode. I work with PHP 7.1

Comment: When you have Joomla support questions, please post them at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Instead:

```
JApplicationCli::getInstance('Importdata')->execute();
```

Use:

```
$app = JApplicationCli::getInstance('Importdata');
$app->set('debug', 0);
$app->execute();
```

Comment: If you can provide support for Joomla questions, please lend us a hand at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: That doesn't solve the memory leak. define('JDEBUG', false) neither.